# Python: Users choosing either an int or a float

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, int, user-input

This may be a really basic question, but I'm kind of new to Python. I'm building a simple distance conversion tool and I'd like to have the user get the option to input a float or an int, depending on their measurement. Other than a billion if statements (one for each unit of measurement, like inches to centimeters or feet to meters), is there a decent way to do this?

EDIT: Here is a snippet of my code

```
#if imperial, offer choices of inch, foot, or mile
if disType == "i":
    print """
    What unit of measurement do you want to convert?
    inches to centimeters: i
    feet to meters: f
    miles to kilometers: m
    """
    unitType = raw_input(prompt)
    #if unit is inches, prompt user for number of
    #inches and convert to centimeters
    if unitType == "i":
        print "Please input distance in inches"
        inches = int(raw_input(prompt))
        centimeters = inches * 2.54
        print "That is %i centimeters" % centimeters
```

If the user inputs a decimal, I want to be able to account for it. But I have one of these if statements for every conversion (six conversions in distance alone). I'd rather not add an if statement for each one that branches off in the case of a float.

Comment: do you always want it converting from imperial to metric?

Comment: The user inputs a string. You can convert that to either an int or a float as needed. And -- what in the world does int vs float have to do with choice of units? Fractional values can be used in any system.

Comment: Please post a snippet of your code or give a clear example of what you want to achieve. 

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between float and int? Just treat everything as float.

Comment: @JohnColeman It has nothing to do with the units themselves, but it has everything to do with giving users the option to input a whole number or a fractional value of measurement. I simply wanted to give you an idea of what I was working in.

And I don't want to deal with the inaccuracies of using floats when I don't have to. I want to use an int if the user originally inputs that, but don't want to limit them to it.

Comment: @RNar I want to give the users a choice to go either way

Comment: @SaicharanSM I have added some of my code.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have trouble in how to implement unit conversions without a bunch of if statements, right?

If I were you, I would do this:

```
conv_func = {
    'inch': func_for_inch_conv,
    'cm': func_for_cm_conv,
    ...
}
data = raw_input() # prompt the user to enter data in the form '1 inch'
mag, unit = data.split(' ')
result = conv_func[unit](mag)
```

I don't know whether this is a good way to solve it, but that's what I think of.